# How do I set up Emgu CV on Visual Studio 2013 for Unit Tests?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, opencv, emgucv, test-explorer

I've got to test in C# some new C++/CLI managed components in a Visual Studio 2013 Unit Test so that it's visible in the Test Explorer.  One of those components uses OpenCV cv::Mat.

It's been recommended that I use Emgu CV for unit tests.  I've installed Emgu CV for Windows x64.

How do I install Emgu in the unit test project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In test project:

- Add reference to Emgu.CV.World.dll
- Add file opencv_coreXXXd.dll

  - XXX = version number
  - Properties | Copy to Output Directory = "Copy Always"
  - Above unit test class add

    - using Emgu.CV;

  See [Setting up EMGU C Sharp](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_EMGU_C_Sharp).